# How to have a Facebook Link Image preview larger than 1200x600,

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I've seen a facebook post with a large image preview, larger than the 1200x600 image preview the facebook is cropping everytime.

Here is the comparison to the facebook post I saw to the one I tried to make:

[Larger Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBXRK.png)

[My post which is obviously shorter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WKho.png)

If anyone wants to go take a look at the post, then you can take a look here:

Page: [Here](https://www.facebook.com/chllx2018)

FB post: [Here](https://m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=pfbid029K1JVmNNQuSdLyvoAQfuGHYQGB7Xis5YBuPs78p1zU4hdCxYyAzTu1mY4JeQsTApl&id=100044553968732&mibextid=Nif5oz)

Something I also noticed about the page's posts are the links image preview are different from the actual preview when you used the fb debugger tool.

If you click the fb post above, you will go to this link: [here](https://shopee.ph/product/6381125/2645834321?utm_campaign=-&utm_content=----&utm_medium=affiliates&utm_source=an_13303290008&utm_term=9fiorc3mv631)
but when i check the preview data of the link above, a different data shows, see below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UufM.png)

I tried many things, from tweaking different picture dimensions and aspect ratios, coding different meta tags, making sure files are properly cached by fb using debugger tool, etc. just to produce a larger link image preview but to no avail. I read a ton of different articles regarding the subject matter but nothing seems to be working.

I'm perplexed on how did he managed to change the link preview data, I tried editing using meta business suite with verified domain but the only thing that you can edit in the post is the description. Any help will be much appreciated thank you :)